# How to wire lighting fixture with two sets of hot, neutral, and ground?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture, rewire

I'm installing a light fixture in my crawl space. The fixture has a set of hot, neutral, and ground wires coming into the fixture from utilities as well as a set of hot, neutral, and ground wires coming into the fixture from our radon system (see image below).

[image: Original light fixture wiring]

The hot and neutral wires had wirenuts connecting them together for the radon system to operate. The radon system was installed as part of our purchase for the home, so this is the first time I'm looking at this light fixture. Would it be OK to tighten both wires of the same type (hot, neutral, ground) under the relevant screws of the light fixture? I've started to connect the light fixture with one wire of each, as shown below.

[image: Latest light fixture wiring]

If both wires under each screw is not OK, would I need to cut a wire section in order to pigtail three ends of each wire type together, like in the image from [this blog](https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/electrical/q-a-to-pigtail-or-not-to-pigtail_o)?

**UPDATE** Taking advice to pigtail (thanks, @nobody !), I'm assuming that the wiring diagram would look something like this. Would I still want to have one ground wire under a light housing screw, like in the first picture?

[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: I take it we're talking about a pullchain lampholder here?

Comment: Correct, this is for a pullchain lampholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t get multiple wires under screws like that securely. Make pigtails (separate pieces of wire about six inches long should do), wirenut them to the wires going in/out of the box, and put the free ends of the pigtails on the screws.

Comment: Since the OP erroneously called the connected wires in the box  pigtails, it may be helpful for you  to give a detailed description of exactly what a pigtail is and how it is used in this situation.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that the wires were just connected with a wirenut and not a pigtail after a bit more research. Thanks for the clarification! I've updated my post to add a wiring diagram of what's being suggested. Is that correct?